# How do people usually operate information on server database?

Tags: python, sql, rdbms

I have a server with a database, the server will listen for http requests, and using JSONs for 
data transferring.

Currently, what my server code(python) mainly do is read the JSON file, convert it to SQL and make some modifications to the database. And the function of the server, as I see, is only like a converter between JSON and SQL. Is this the right procedure that people usually do?

Then I come up with another idea, I can define a class for user information and every user's information in the database is an instance of that class. When I get the JSON file, first I put it into the instance, do some operation and then put it into the database. In my understanding, it adds a language layer between the http request and the database.

The question is, what do people usually do?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: people do usually that, what they need to do. The layer between database and client normally provides a higher level api, to make the request independent from the actual database. But how this higher level looks like depends on the application you have.

Answer (score 0):

People usually make use of a Web framework, instead of implementing the basic machinery themselves as you are doing.

That is: Python i s a great language that easily allows one to translate "json into sql" with a small amount of code - and it is great for learning. If you are doing this for educational purposes, it is a nice project to continue fiddling with, and maybe you can have some nice ideas in this answer and in others.

But for "real world" usage, the apparent simple plan comes up with real world issues. Tens or even hundreds of them. How to proper separate html/css template from content from core logic, how to deal with many, many aspects of security, etc...

Them, the frameworks come into play: a web-framewrok project is a software project that had, over the years, and soemtimes hundreds of hours of work from several contributors, thought about, and addresses all of the issues a real web application can and will face.

So, it is ok if one want to to everything from scratch if he believes he can come up with a a framework taht has distinguished capabilities not available in any existing project. And it is ok to make small projects for learning purposes. It is **not** ok to try to come up with something from scratch for real server production, without having a deep knowledge of all the issues involved, and knowing well at least 3, 4 frameworks.

So, now, you've got the basic understanding of a way to get to a framework - it istime to learn some of the frameworks tehmselves. Try, for example, Bottle and Flask (microframeworks), and Django (a fully featured framework for web application development), maybe Tornado (an http server, but with enough of a web framework in it to be usable, and to be very instructive)- just reading the documentation on "how to get started" with these projects, to get to a "hello world" page will lead you to lots of concepts you probably had not thought about yet.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and I have another question: When we do something small without database, we may design a class, create some instances and do operation on these instances. Then when we use the database, we put the information into the database. And what I'm wondering is do we still need those instances? Or every operation we do, we communicate directly with the database?

Comment: That is the role of a software layer known as "ORM" - Object Relational Mapper - like in the text above, you can gradually roll out your own - but the existing ones, most notably "SQLAlchemy" will take care of a lot of issues and corner cases. For you specific doubt, you have to be careful to keep things in sync - I 'd prefer to have the object in memory, with a explicit method on the class to commit the object data to the database, rather than expecting it to be done automatically, for example, on object destruction.